# Adjust for time offset with plugin data

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I get a stream of data from my router via syslog which I want to publish to a New Relic plugin. There's a lag of about 4 minutes before I have the data available so the times shown in New Relic don't match up with times of other related events in New Relic. How do I make New Relic adjust for the time offset?

Answer (score 3):

Our goal is to create a platform where you can report a stream of data collected from your applications environment that is actionable and can be used to monitor the performance of your application.

Metrics reported to New Relic always end at the time in which they are reported. In cases where you have a time lag issue such as this the graphs will be offset. You may wish to consider documenting the charts time lag in the graphs title or sub-title.